# Meaning of C++0x auto keyword, by example?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

```
auto a = (Foo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Foo<T>));
auto *b = (Foo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Foo<T>));
```

I don't think it's important that templates are there, but the question is: are `a` and `b` of the same type?

`g++ -std=c++0x -Wall` (4.4) doesn't give any errors or warnings, but I haven't run the program so I don't know if it does the same thing.

Does this mean that for `a`, `auto` is `Foo<T>*`, but for `b`, `auto` is `Foo<T>`?

Comment: Just wondering: why `(Foo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Foo<T>))` instead of `new Foo<T>` ?

Comment: What is that "new" thing? Just kidding. It's part of some multithreaded code about message passing, where I wanted simple and fast rules. "free" just releases the memory and lets you know it's your responsability to do anything else you might have to do. "delete", however, can call virtual destructors (slower), and can call into destructors which may have side effects, randomly breaking multithreaded code. It's really just so I don't accidently put a member variable in a message that has a destructor with side effects; without it being obvious by reading the code. "delete p;" is so cryptic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> are `a` and `b` of the same type?

Let's find out, shall we?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T member;
};

template <typename T>
void test()
{
    auto  a = (Foo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Foo<T>));
    auto *b = (Foo<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Foo<T>));

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value, "same type");
}

template void test<int>();   // explicit instantiation
```

This compiles without a static assertion failure.

> Does this mean that for `a`, `auto` is `Foo<T>*`, but for `b`, `auto` is `Foo<T>`?

Yes.

Comment: Worse, it hides the theoretical possibility that `typeid(a) != typeid (b)`.

Comment: @MSalters: Maybe I'm not following, but those must compare equal if they are the same type (though they don't have to be the same object). @Fred: Maybe a better answer would just be an `is_same` meta-function and printing `is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value`.

Comment: @GMan: your statement is correct, but weak. You can't invert it. I.e. "they _may or may not_ compare inequal if they are not the same type". Because of this weakness, your (previous) `static_assert` does not conclusively establish that `a` and `b` are the same type.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `auto` as a placeholder. In your example the declared types of `a` and `b` are same. The only difference is that `auto` is deduced to be the pointer itself in the first case whereas in the second case it is deduced to be just `Foo<T>`.

Except for one special case, auto works just like template argument deduction with a function:

```
template<class U>
void func_a(U);

template<class U>
void func_b(U*);

template<class T> struct Foo {};

template<class T>
void test() {
   func_a( new Foo<T> ); // U = Foo<T>*
   func_b( new Foo<T> ); // U = Foo<T>
}
```

In your example `auto` is deduced just like the type parameter `U` in the above code.

The special case I was talking about are initializer lists:

```
void test2() {
    auto x = {1,2,3};  // OK, decltype(x) --> initializer_list<int>
    func_a( {1,2,3} ); // Illegal, U cannot be deduced because
                       // {1,2,3} is not considered an expression
}
```

Apart from this special case, the deduction rules are the same.