# What is the simplest example using auto in C++?

Tags: c++, auto

I try to understand how `auto` is used in C++. For me the best way to understand something is to see an example. However, the examples that I saw are not so simple. For example here is "[Meaning of C++0x auto keyword, by example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784804/meaning-of-c0x-auto-keyword-by-example)". To understand this example I need to know what are "templates", "pointers", "malloc" and so on.

Can anybody, please, give an minimalistic example using auto so one can easy understand what it is used for?

Comment: Your question is not actually about "auto". It is about "templates", "pointers", "malloc" and so on. If you don't know what they are, just don't worry about "auto" yet - get a good book to learn from.

Comment: Do not even have to get a book - Google to the rescue - http://login2win.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/c-auto.html

Comment: Difficult to pin down to a specific "this is it" meaning. I can only offer this. It is useful for automagic deduction of "type" from the code *context* in which it is used. Thats about as "blanket" as I can get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

auto c = a+b; // c will be int
```

Answer (score 12):

`auto` is used for type inference, i.e. to declare a type based on the expression, instead of explicitly stating it.

```
auto val = 3; // here, val is declared as an integer
```

Obviously this isn't such a big advantage over `int val = 3` so let's make a better example:

```
std::vector<int> container; // ...
for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
    // type of it is std::vector<int>::iterator, but you don't need to state that
}
```

here you don't have to care about the real container type, i.e. `std::vector<int>::iterator it = c.begin()`. Additionally, you can change `container` from vector to list, and the loop would still work without any changes as type of `it` would be correctly deduced.

NOTE: in C++11 you would write the loop above as `for( auto it: container)` but this serves better as an illustration.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` is useful to avoid typing verbose names, which is what you usually get with templates. But in general, the pattern goes like this:

```
struct my_class_with_a_long_name { };

my_class_with_a_long_name foo()
{
    my_class_with_a_long_name obj;
    // ...
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    auto myObj = foo();
}
```

But it's not just about typing less characters, it is also about *consistency*. If you change the return type of `foo`, you won't have to explicitly change also the type of `myObj`.

Basically, the point is that when the type of a certain expression is known to the compiler at compile-time, there is no reason for not exploiting this knowledge and letting the compiler use it automatically, in whatever context this can be done.

The only situation where you likely do *not* want to use `auto` is when you want to perform *conversions*, or when you want the type of a variable to appear explicit before its declaration for readability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know what `std::vector<int>` is (basically a resizable array of integers).

Let's say you have just such a vector, and want to iterate over its elements. Here, `auto` comes in very handy:

```
std::vector<int> items;
...
for (auto iter = std::begin(items); iter != std::end(items); ++iter) {
    // do something with `iter'
}
```

While `iter` is conceptually simple (it's an iterator), it has a somewhat complex type (`std::vector<int>::iterator`). Using `auto` saves you having to spell out the type. It also makes it easier to change the type of `items` to some other container.